# When to use Spring WebMVC's Views and/or MessageConverters?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am writing an inhouse app with Spring 3.1.3 with UI for humans utilizing the VelocityView and with a REST API which serializes response entities as JSON or XML.

Now, besides the view and messageconverter thing. When would one use one of theses? I presumed that views are for humans as a general rule and messageconverters for M2M communication. Why do Views like JsonView, XmlView, etc. exist? Those outputs aren't for humans anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially right - View is to convert the internal model into a "viewable" format - be it html, json, xml etc, so MappingJackJsonView, newer Marshalling View etc, if used as a view take in all the elements set in the model and transform them to xml.

`MessageConverters` on the other hand do things a little differently, it doesn't work on the model attributes, it works instead on the response body - transforming the response body to the appropriate format based on the ACCEPT header of the request.

Comment: Thanks, where would one ever need a JsonView? Humans don't need JSON anyway.

Comment: If you say want to convert one model attribute to json/xml or want to transform a model attribute to xml/json without regards for the ACCEPT header of request then you can use JsonView, but you are right, it is more a legacy stuff than anything else

Comment: OK, I see. Ignores the requested content type by the client but serves the one I return in my code.